# Error "Aws-sdk-java" conflict with maven

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, aws-java-sdk

I am having conflict problem using aws-sdk-java and I no longer know what to do.

I already tried several things and I researched several topics and I can not solve.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.enable (Lcom / fasterxml / jackson / core / JsonParser $ Feature;) Lcom / fasterxml / jackson / databind / ObjectMapper;

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.matheus.api</groupId>
<artifactId>matheus.api</artifactId>
<version>1.0.25.1</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>matheus.api</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.78</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.25</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20170516</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1208.jre7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-security-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-calendar</artifactId>
        <version>v3-rev262-1.23.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava-jdk5</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sns</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Oh sorry,  Thanks!!!

Comment: Please update your question with the complete stack trace, in a code block rather than a quote.

Comment: Also, please verify that you are running the code that you think you are. I ran `mvn dependency:tree` on the POM that you posted, and there should be no reason for you to get this error: the `<dependencyManagement>` section forces version consistency for the Jackson dependency. Without that section, you do have an older `jackson-core` dependency being pulled in, and that version doesn't have the method in question.

Comment: The `<dependencyManagement>` section is the simplest way to avoid incompatible transitive dependencies, but you do have to look at the dependency tree and make sure that you catch everything (Jackson is particularly painful in this respect because it has lots of artifacts). And you do risk using a too-new dependency that breaks backwards compatibility (but there's no way around that).

Comment: @kdgregory thanks for the feedback, even using <dependencyManagement> the problem remains strange that this only happens when I publish in AWS Elastic BeanStalk, but locally on my computer I do not have the problem

Answer (score 2):

You may want to checkout the [bundle](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-bundle) dependency rather than taking the dependency in through the BOM. Better explained [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/java-sdk-bundle/), but it effectively bundles (and relocates) all of the third-party classes required for the AWS SDK for Java into a single uber JAR - rather than trying to resolve dependencies transitively. It does this using the Maven Shade plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but use bundle is extremely large 60 mb this way project gets huge.

Comment: Yes, that is the downside. The other option is that you could build a version of the SDK from source yourself and include it in your project. Checkout the Maven [Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) Plugin, of course this means managing builds/artifacts yourself.

Comment: Do you have any examples? Tks